# Why this Prolog code doesn't work like expected

Tags: prolog

This seems kind of silly but this Prolog code returns true for all values from 1 to 100. While it should be only for 55 numbers . Can somebody explain, what am I missing here?

```
num(I) :- between(1,100,I).
cond(I) :- num(I), I + 100/I > 50.
query(cond(_)).
```

Comment: Let's try 2; `num(2)` is true, because 2 is between 1 and 100; `cond(2)` is true because 2 + 100/2 = 52 > 50. Also, 49 works (because 49 + 100/49 = 51), and so does any greater number.

Comment: @AlexP ,try for 10, num(10) is true but (10 + 100/10) = 20. So It should be false for [3,47].

Comment: What Prolog implementation are you using? With SWI Prolog, cond(3) is false for me.

Comment: `num(10)` is true because 10 is between 1 and 100. That's the only condition that your rule `num(X)` puts on `X`. Your `I + 100/I > 50` condiition is part of your `cond(I)` clause.

Comment: sorry, It is cond(10).

Comment: @ArndtJonasson, I am using [Problog](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/problog/index.html)

Comment: When I run your code, problog gives me 55 lines.

Comment: I don't know, what was the problem, but it works now.